# How to prevent `()` added during company completions

Tags: company

In [company-mode](https://company-mode.github.io), when I apply `company-complete-selection`, it completes variable but sometimes adds `()` at the end of it. Would it be possible to prevent this in all cases?

Example:
[image]

which completed as: `self.logged_jobs_to_process()`

---

my setup:

```
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)
(setq company-auto-commit t)
(setq company-auto-complete t)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-k") 'company-complete)
(setq company-frontends
      '(company-pseudo-tooltip-unless-just-one-frontend
        company-preview-frontend
        company-echo-metadata-frontend))
```

---

`M-x company-diag` returns:

```
Emacs 28.0.50 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) of 2021-09-01 on home
Company 0.9.13

company-backends: (company-bbdb company-semantic company-cmake company-capf company-clang company-files
              (company-dabbrev-code company-gtags company-etags company-keywords)
              company-oddmuse company-dabbrev)

Used backend: company-capf
Value of c-a-p-f: (lsp-completion-at-point)
Major mode: python-mode
Prefix: "None"
Completions:
  #("None" 0 4 (lsp-completion-item #s(hash-table size 7 test equal rehash-size 1.5 rehash-threshold 0.8125 data ("label" #("None" 0 4 (match-data (0 4 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4))) "kind" 14
"sortText" "aNone" "insertText" "None" "data" #s(hash-table size 1 test equal rehash-size 1.5 rehash-threshold 0.8125 data ("doc_uri" "file:///home/alper/ebloc-broker/broker/Driver.py"))
"_emacsStartPoint" 3652)) lsp-sort-text "aNone" lsp-completion-start-point 3652 lsp-completion-markers (3652 #<marker (moves after insertion) at 3656 in Driver.py>) lsp-completion-prefix
"None" match-data (0 4 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4) face (completions-common-part))) " (Keyword)"
```

Comment: Hey @alper. As a side note, you can safely remove `company-auto-commit` from your setup, because this is an obsolete name of `company-auto-complete`, which you also have enabled.

Comment: Yikes, and there was no reason to [double-post](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/discussions/1218), I think?

Comment: @Y.E. I know, sorry I was desperate to find an solution :( I think I cannot delete an opened issue, I closed the issue over there for clearity.

Comment: no problem, I understand that "was desperate" part :-) The `Issue` you had submitted was moved to the `Discussions` section there. [I'd do the same, but the maintainer was the first one around.] Overall, it's totally welcome to post/lookup `Company` questions at its [Q&A](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/discussions/categories/q-a) section. Moreover, often you'd get a faster response there (f.i., as you'd noticed, the maintainer is very responsive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATED]

After the output of `M-x company-diag` was posted it became clear, according to the `Value of c-a-p-f: (lsp-completion-at-point)`, that `lsp-mode` is responsible for the completion in this case.

Eventually, after contacting both `lsp-mode` and `python-lsp-server` maintainers, it was clarified that this `lsp-mode` setting has to be disabled to prevent completion with parentheses:

```
(setq lsp-enable-snippet nil)
```

[EARLIER ANSWER, suitable for the `company-clang` backend.]

I assume that the backend in action is `company-clang`.

(If not, add the output of `M-x company-diag` to your question.)

Then, the addition of the parentheses can be prevented by disabling this `company-clang` *user option*:

```
(setq company-clang-insert-arguments nil)
```

But note that it's going to *disable* insertion of arguments.

For example,

[image]

Completes to

[image]

only if [`company-clang-insert-arguments`](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/issues/102) is enabled.

Comment: Output for `M-x company-diag` is added. I have tried `(setq company-clang-insert-arguments nil)` but still it adds `()` to the end for example for the Variables that are assigned to None, completed as `variable_name()`

Comment: I think used backend is `company-capf` but I am not sure how can I disabled in the it

Comment: As you correctly noted at the `Company` [Q&A](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/discussions/1218#discussioncomment-1360930), `Value of c-a-p-f: (lsp-completion-at-point)` shows `lsp-mode` is responsible for the completion. To be more precise, I expect that would be not `lsp-mode` itself, but the Python **server** you have installed.

Comment: Yes, excatly I have installed it using: `pip install "python-lsp-server[all]"` and I believe activated using: `(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'lsp)`. I can share more information related to my lsp setup if its required

Comment: Sorry, I don't use `lsp-mode` or `Python`, so cannot help with the details. I'd suggest following the advice given in [this lsp-mode Issue](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/issues/1033).

Comment: All good, should I carry my issue into https://github.com/python-lsp/python-lsp-server ?

Comment: I'd do so, yes. And, for reference, I see you [already did](https://github.com/python-lsp/python-lsp-server/issues/89). And if you find a solution it'd be nice if you post it in here and in Company's `Q&A` (for future generations so to speak :-)

Comment: Their only response was: `It does not work like that in other editors, so it would seem that either:

the company-mode uses label when it should be using insertText (most likely)
you have snippets enabled (which are disabled by default)`

Comment: It sounds as `lsp-mode` job rather than `company`. `lsp-mode` handles all the communication with the server. All `company` does in this case is outputting completions sent by `lsp-mode`. So I'd suggest contacting `lsp-mode` maintainers as the next step.

Comment: https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/issues/3116

Comment: (a joke: "it is server bug" => you're in infinite loop now ;) Jokes aside, I hope advice to "disable snippets by setting lsp-enable-snippet to nil." solves the issue for you.

Comment: I am expert to put myself into infinite loop :) The thing is I want to use snippets  (https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Yasnippet) :-( I am not sure are they connected

Comment: [Seems so](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/search?q=lsp-enable-snippet).

Comment: Please note that doing `(setq lsp-enable-snippet nil)` solved it

Comment: I updated the answer accordingly. Feel free to update as you see fit.